# Callback function that creates elements return element with empty innerHTML

Tags: javascript, callback, dom-events, innerhtml

I have a function that creates a li element with buttons. But when I call it via an eventListener, the element created in return was just a list without the innerHTML content.

What's happening and how do I fix that?
Here's my JS script:

```
const inputField = document.querySelector("input.inputField");
const addToList = document.querySelector("input.addToList");
const list = document.querySelector("div.list");

createTodo = () => {
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  let up = "<button class='up'>Up</button>";
  li.innerHTML += up;
  let down = "<button class='down'>Down</button>";
  li.innerHTML += down;
  let remove = "<button class='remove'>Remove</button>";
  li.innerHTML += remove;
  return li;
};

addToList.addEventListener("click", () => {
  let todo = inputField.value;
  var li = createTodo();
  console.log(li);
  li.textContent = todo;
  list.appendChild(li);
  inputField.value = "";
});
```

Comment: You need to add the element into the DOM before modifying the innerHTML property.

Comment: You're overwriting it here: `li.textContent = todo;` Maybe you meant to use `+=`.

Comment: @JonášKulhánek: You can work with it outside the DOM. It's still a DOM element like any other.

Comment: @slappy I wouldnt say he his, textContent just inserts the text and buttons remain in the html

Comment: @EugenSunic: Sorry, but no. Setting the content of  DOM element erases existing content. https://jsfiddle.net/f5L2jgt6/

Comment: Though my `+=` suggestion was wrong. That'll erase element nodes too, and only keep text nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're destroying the existing element nodes in the `li` when you do this:

```
li.textContent = todo;
```

What you could instead do is use `.insertAdjacentText()` to append new text nodes without losing the element nodes.

```
li.insertAdjacentText("beforeend", todo);
```

---

Also, generally using `+=` with `.innerHTML` can cause problems. It's not too bad in your code, but there are better ways, for example using `.insertAdjacentHTML()`.

And the multiple insertions seems more verbose than needed. I'd do this instead:

```
const createTodo = () => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <button class='up'>Up</button>
    <button class='down'>Down</button>
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
  `;
  return li;
};
```

---

And then why not have your function receive the `todo` text as an argument? You can then use string interpolation to make it really simple:

```
const inputField = document.querySelector("input.inputField");
const addToList = document.querySelector("input.addToList");
const list = document.querySelector("div.list");

const createTodo = (todo) => {
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", `
    <button class='up'>Up</button>
    <button class='down'>Down</button>
    <button class='remove'>Remove</button>
    ${todo}
  `;
  return li;
};

addToList.addEventListener("click", () => {
  list.appendChild(createTodo(inputField.value));
  inputField.value = "";
});
```